# Quantum fidelity commutativity proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, commutator, density-operator

I am looking for a proof that the [quantum fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) $$F(\rho, \sigma) = \left(\text{tr} \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt\rho}\right)^2$$ is commutative, i.e. $F(\rho, \sigma) = F(\sigma, \rho)$.

I have been able to find some proofs (such as [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/TQI.pdf)); however, they are quite involved and force the reader to understand different topics (such as measure theory).

Is there more straightforward proof of the fact?

Comment: Please give the exact reference (e.g. chapter, page, equation)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the operators $\rho$ and $\sigma$ act in a finite-dimensional space, then you can easily see that all nonzero eigenvalues of the operators $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}$ and $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho\!\sqrt{\sigma}$ coincide. Indeed, let's consider the eigenvector $\Psi$ of the  operator $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}$ corresponding to a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then the following equality holds
$$
\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \Psi = \lambda \Psi \qquad (1)
$$
From this equality we proceed to
$$
\lambda \sqrt{\sigma}\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \Psi = \sqrt{\sigma}\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \Psi = \sqrt{\sigma}\rho \sqrt{\sigma}\ \sqrt{\sigma}\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \Psi.\quad (2)
$$
Vector $\Phi = \sqrt{\sigma}\!\sqrt{\rho}\ \Psi$ is nonzero, otherwise $\lambda$ would be zero according to (1). Therefore equality (2) means that $\Phi$ is the eigenvector of the operator $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho \sqrt{\sigma}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. I think it is now obvious that the operators $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sigma}\rho \sqrt{\sigma}}$ and $\sqrt{\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}}$ have the same trace. Two operators have the same eigenvalues, then their square roots have the same eigenvalues, then the traces of the square roots of these operators are equal.

I believe that in the case of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, a similar consideration is possible when $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are density matrices.

Addition. In the case where degenerate eigenvalues are present, additional analogous consideration is required to ensure that the operators $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\!\sqrt{\rho}$ and $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho\!\sqrt{\sigma}$ have equal numbers of each of the eigenvalues.

Addition 2. Let's consider the case of degenerate eigenvalues. Suppose that the operator $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt{\rho}$ has exactly $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors $\Psi_i$, $i = 1,\ldots,k$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. In this case, for any numbers $a_i$, $i =1,\ldots,k$, $\sum_{i=1}^k|a_i| \neq 0$ we have that the vector $\Psi(a) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \Psi_i$ is also an eigenvector of the operator $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt{\rho}$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. According to the previous consideration, all vectors $\Phi(a) = \sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho} \Psi(a)$ are (nonzero) eigenvectors of the operator $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho\sqrt{\sigma} $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Taking into account the arbitrariness in the choice of the coefficients $a$, the latter fact means that the vectors $\Phi_i = \sqrt{\sigma}\sqrt{\rho} \Psi_i$ are $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors of the operator $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho\sqrt{\sigma}$. This reasoning can also be carried out the other way, whence it follows that the operators $\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt{\rho}$ and $\sqrt{\sigma}\rho\sqrt{\sigma}$ have exactly the same number of eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: You state that since $\sqrt\sigma\rho\sqrt\sigma$ and $\sqrt\rho\sigma\sqrt\rho$ have the same trace, their square roots do as well. Why? Also, in case of degenerate eigenvalues, I cannot see how we can save the proof :)

Comment: @SlowerPhoton I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define [square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Square_roots_of_positive_operators) $R:=\sqrt{\rho}$ and $S:=\sqrt{\sigma}$. Both $R,S$ are [semi-positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_operator_(Hilbert_space)) bounded operators. Define the bounded operator $T:= SR$. Notice that $T^{\dagger}=RS$.
2. The definition of [quantum fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) then becomes the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class)
   $$ \sqrt{F(\rho, \sigma)} ~=~ {\rm tr}|T|, \tag{1}$$
   because the absolute value operator $|T|$ satisfies
   $$ |T|~=~\sqrt{T^{\dagger}T}.\tag{2} $$
3. The [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space) yields
   $$ T~=~U|T|\qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad|T|~=~U^{\dagger}T,\tag{3}$$
   where $U$ is a [partial isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry) with
   $$ {\rm ker} U~=~{\rm ker} T .\tag{4}$$
4. This leads to
   $$ |T^{\dagger}|~=~U|T| U^{\dagger}, \tag{5}$$
   and in turn OP's sought-for relation
   $$ \sqrt{F(\sigma,\rho)} ~=~ {\rm tr}|T^{\dagger}| ~=~ {\rm tr}|T| ~=~\sqrt{F(\rho, \sigma)} \tag{6}$$
   by cyclicity of the trace.